# How to display notification before form submit with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to hold form submission to display notification for a couple of seconds?

Before a page reloads after the callback form is submitted I would like to display something along those lines: "Thank you for your callback request. We will be in touch shortly."

Comment: The "Request a callback" feature? Why does the page need to reload? I.e. post the form in the background using ajax then display a message? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form)

Comment: It's pretty straightfoward to run a function on submit that returns true after some other event. What have you tried?

Comment: Please keep the question directly answerable. Answers are not supposed to recommend ideas, but cut to the chase of your problem. Also, dumping a link in order for us to look for something is also not optimal. Instead, post relevant code. Your site is prone to change, and the question will lose context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting, show the information you want and submit() the form in a setTimout() after the desired delay.

Comment: there's always `window.confirm();` as an option to a setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

if you're submitting with AJAX there is no need to refresh.

Take this as an example:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fname"/>
  <input type="text" name="lname"/>
  <input type="text" name="email"/>
  <input type="text" name="address"/>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  <!--
     Here you have two options. Use <a></a> or an input with type="submit"
     since you're using AJAX, I reccomend using <a href="#" id="submit_form">Submit</a>
  -->
  <a href="#" id="submit_form">Submit</a>
</form>
```

Thank you for your callback request. We will be in touch shortly.

On javascript then:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit_form").bind("click",function(){
     //do a $.post();
     $.post("submit/this.php",something : "content_of_something",
       function(response){
          if(response==1)//or whatever you want
            $('#some_id').fadeIn(function() {
               setTimeout(function(){
                 window.location.reload();
               },3000);                         
            });
          else
            alert("Error ocurred");
       }
     );


    });
  });
</script>
```

On PHP, check if the variable got to the server through $_POST(for debug purpose do var_export($_POST) on the server and on the client put a alert(response) right after function(response)). If everything went how it was supposed, echo 1(so response will match 1== response == 1), else, you can echo something else you want.